# Adding Endpoint in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a service, which works on URL like this `http://localhost:1253/NotificationProducer`

Then I try to add an endpoint on server-side, which will listen to URL like this: `http://localhost:1253/NotificationProducer/1`

BasemanagerRefernce is `http://localhost:1253/NotificationProducer`

```
ServiceHost svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(NotificationProducer), new Uri( BaseResources.baseManagerReference ));

svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(INotificationProducer),
                           new WSHttpBinding(),
                           new Uri(BaseResources.baseManagerReference),
                           new Uri(BaseResources.baseManagerReference+"/"+id));

List<string> endpointslist = new List<string>();

foreach (var endpoint in svcHost.Description.Endpoints)
{
    .Add(endpoint.Address.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

But after all this manipulations my endpointslist contains only `http://localhost:1253/NotificationProducer`
and when i programmatically change endpoint adress in my client to `http://localhost:1253/NotificationProducer/1` i catch an error which tells me,that there is no listener on this address.

So how can I add an endpoint or listener correctly? Sorry, but i'am kinda newbie at WCF and didn't work with such features and hadn't found an answer on msdn.

Comment: Quick question: are you opening your hosting service? Did you use the command svcHost.Open(); method? After doing this, your serviceHost will stay open until you call svcHost.Close();.

Comment: I guess no, i didn't. Where should i do this? I will need some service factory, which will manage my endpoints?

Comment: Open it after you've loaded the configuration and / or defined your endpoints in code

Comment: Aphelion is right. Basically what you did was configure your endpoints but you didn't start your service host. That's why you got the message saying that there were no endpoints listening.

Comment: Any reason why you're using the overload of `AddServiceEndpoint` with 4 parameters? Calling `AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(INotificationProducer), new WSHttpBinding(), BaseResources.baseManagerReference + "/" + id);` should work.